# TypeScript ternary operator hides type error - how to rewrite to use typecheck?

Tags: typescript, ternary-operator

I have following code working with interface `IObject`:

```
interface IObject {
  foo?: boolean;
}

const bool = true;
const fooBar: IObject = bool ? {
  foo: 'not boolean', // should be boolean only
  notExisting: '132' // should not exist
} : {};  // only this type is considered to be returned
```

Issue with code is that even that it has strict typings everywhere, it's possible to fill in wrong object.

*Looks like it's TypeScript issue based [on this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14758)*

My question is what's the best way to write code like this, but keep type safety?

Is possible to do so without using `let` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript performs excess property checking on [*non-empty* object literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14606#issuecomment-285956509) only.  This, I suppose, is usually beneficial to developers, although it is potentially confusing and has some strange side effects, like you just found.

The easiest workaround here is to explicitly assert that the empty object literal is an `IObject` so that the compiler never turns off excess property checking:

```
const fooBar: IObject = bool ? {
  foo: 'not boolean', 
  notExisting: '132'  
} : ({} as IObject);  // assertion fixes it
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!